# On Travis how do I modify tests to use minitest instead of rspec?

Tags: ruby, github, rspec, travis-ci, minitest

The link for ask question on Travis dot com sent me here. My tests fail because I'm using minitest in my gem but travis uses rspec. Is there a way to get travis to do that also? Of course I can always modify my tests to use rspec but I'm not sure how to get tests or spec from my structure of my tests. They all have assert_equal which is not recognized by respec as a valid method. Is there a common way to make either test work with the same *_spec.rb files?

Comment: Where are you seeing that Travis CI assumes rspec? We only run `bundle exec rake test` for Ruby projects.

Comment: Well thanks for that info. Now maybe I can look for another reason why my code wont build on travis-ci. Any hints for the script in .travis.yml? I probably have something wrong there then. I used rbenv: and travis might not like that. Should I use rvm: then?

Comment: Yup, rvm is the way to go to determine the Ruby version you'd like to use.

Comment: I have since resolved the problem by doing explicitly what is required for several good builds of different rubies. Thanks for the comments. It wasn't the tests it was the environment I was trying to use. Silly me thought that I could get away with rbenv.

Answer (score 1):

This is another option to run your test in your .travis.yml:

```
script:
    - bin/rails test
```

Remeber to install the gems before run the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I found in [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build) that it is possible to define custom commands for running tests (rather than the default `bundle exec rake test`) by placing these lines in `.travis.yml`

```
script:
- bundle exec rake build
- bundle exec rake builddoc
```